# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (intermediate value).toLocalDateString is not a function at Stats.js:62

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, compiler-errors, frontend

```
function Stats() {
  const [customerList, setCustomerList] = useState([]); //store all that information of the database in a list
  //make an axios request to get information from database
  const getCustomers = () => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/customers").then((response) => {
      //console.log("successfully retrieved customers list from database");
      console.log(response.data);
      setCustomerList(response.data);
    });
  };

  {/*}
    const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(1);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch("/time")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setCurrentTime(data.time);
        });
    }, []);
  

    useEffect(() => {
      fetch("/time")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          const dateStr = new Date(data.time).toLocalDateString('en-CA');
          const timeStr = new Date(data.time).toLocalTimeString();
          const dateTime = `${dateStr} ${timeStr}`;
          setCurrentTime(dateTime);
        });
    }, []);
    */}
    
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="container">
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>
      <button onClick={getCustomers}>Show Dashboard</button>
      </div>
      <table className="customertable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>S/N</th>
          <th>Customer Name</th>
          <th>Customer Email</th>
          <th>Counts of Visit</th>
          <th>Latest Time of Visit</th>
          <th>Contacted?</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {customerList.map((val, key) => {
          const dateStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocalDateString('en-CA');
          const timeStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocalTimeString();
          const dateTime = `${dateStr} ${timeStr}`;
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{val.ID}</td>
              <td>{val.name}</td>
              <td>{val.email}</td>
              <td>{val.counts_of_visit}</td>
              <td>{dateTime}</td>
              <td>{val.contacted}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        },)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Stats;
```

here is the code I used the error happens at:
This error happens when I click on `"Show Dashboard"` button which calls a `getCustomer` function on click, does anyone have any solution to this error? when I click the button. I left out the import statements, but in case you need them let me know or comment! Appreciate your help!

```
const dateStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocalDateString('en-CA');
```

Comment: Initially there are no values in your array. Try `customerList.length && customerList.map(...`

Comment: it's spelled locale but not local since you can specify the region code like 'en-CA'

Answer (score 1):

toLocalDateString --> toLocaleDateString

toLocalTimeString --> toLocaleTimeString

Comment: Thank you it works I have another question on my profile do you think you can help on that ?